# Display Image received as response - Vue.js

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, axios, bootstrap-vue

I have used axios to get an image from database

```
          axios.get(`/file/${eventID}/logo1/${name}`,{

                headers:{

                    'Authorization' : `${token}`,
                    'content-type': 'image/png',
                    'accept': 'image/png'
                }
                
            }).then((res) => {

                console.log(res.data)
                this.logo1 = res.data

            }).catch((error) => {

                console.log(error)
            })
```

I am getting the *res.data* in the following format

[image]

I would like to display it in one of my pages.

```
  <b-row>
        <b-col>
            <div>
                <b-img :src="logo1" fluid alt=" "></b-img>
            </div>
        </b-col>
    </b-row>
```

How shall i implement it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i made a small change. Added the response type as blob and then converted it into a URL. Now the image is displayed in fronted.

```
axios.get(`/file/${eventID}/logo1/${name}`,{

            headers:{

                'Authorization' : `${token}`,
                'content-type': 'image/png',
                'accept': 'image/png'
            },
            
            responseType: 'blob'
            
        }).then((res) => {

            const urlCreator = window.URL || window.webkitURL
            this.logo1 = urlCreator.createObjectURL(res.data)

        }).catch((error) => {

            console.log(error)
        })
```

Answer (score 1):

You can attach `data:image/png;base64,` to the base64 encoded logo1.

```
this.logo1 = 'data:image/png;base64,'+ btoa(res.data)
```

Comment: I would suggest Base64 library (http://www.webtoolkit.info), because I've seen somewhere that `btoa()` has some flaws.

Comment: Hi,
ok so i have to convert it to a base64 encoded image and then assign it to this.logo1
@JanMadeyski

Comment: can you let me know the result after you set the logo1 to the base64 code?

Comment: and you can use btoa() method - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/btoa